# Как заставить частицы "скапливаться", а не "разлетаться"?

Tags: unity3d

На картинке ниже изображена чёрная дыра из многим известной игры Stick Fight.
Я попробовал воссоздать её на платформе Unity 3D. И хотелось бы, чтобы частицы вокруг чёрной дыры засасывались внутрь неё. 
Я создал Partical System и в качестве частиц у меня спрайт заранее нарисованной чёрной капли.

Однако наткнулся на две проблемы:

1. Частицы вылетают **из** чёрной дыры, а хотелось бы, чтобы залетали **внутрь**, при этом спавнясь снаружи на дистанции (окружности фиксированного радиуса)
2. Все частицы-капли ориентированы одинаково (все "смотрят" вниз), а хотелось бы, чтобы "смотрели" на чёрную дыру

Таким образом, вопрос - как я могу реализовать пункт 1 и пункт 2?

Где-то читал, что частицами можно в принципе управлять самостоятельно из скрипта, после небольших манипуляций, однако, на мой взгляд, эти проблемы не требуют вмешательства кода.

Спасибо за любую помощь!

[image: Изображение чёрной дыры из игры Stick Fight]

Comment: Со вторым пунктом вроде бы разобрался. В компоненте Particle system > Shape > Align To Direction

Comment: Поставь отрицательную скорость

Comment: попробовал отрицательный Start Speed. Результата нет